# How can I easily determine whether we can interchange integrals over a infinite region?

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification

In his *Partial Differential Equations*, p187, Evans adopts the following method to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac1{1+|y|^2}$, where $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$: he uses $\frac1{1+|y|^2}=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+|y|^2)}\,dt$, and claims that
$$
\left(\frac1{1+|y|^2}\right)^\vee=\frac1{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \int_0^\infty e^{-t}
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{ix\cdot y-t|y|^2}\,dy\right) dt,\quad (*)
$$
thus shifts attention to the evaluation of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{ix\cdot y-t|y|^2}\,dy$.
However I can't see why (*) is correct on the spot. After thinking for a while I managed to justify it.

**My attempt:** I tried to simplify the notation to $\int \left(\int_0^\infty f(t,y) \,dt\right) e^{ixy} dy$, and let $I_b^a(y) =\int_b^a f(t,y) \,dt$. Then we have to show
$$
\int\lim_{a\to +\infty} I_0^a(y)e^{ixy} \,dy=\int_0^{+\infty}\int f(t,y)e^{ixy} \,dydt.
$$
Maybe we should first admit that (Well after some thought I realized that this also requires a justification)
$$
\int I_0^b(y)e^{ixy} \,dy=\int_0^{b}\int f(t,y)e^{ixy} \,dydt
$$
and then prove that
$$
\int\lim_{a\to +\infty} I_0^a(y)e^{ixy}\,dy=\lim_{a\to +\infty} \int I_0^a(y)e^{ixy} \,dy
$$
which is the same as
$$
\left|\int I_b^\infty e^{ixy} dy\right| \text{ can be arbitrarily small as long as } b \text{ is sufficiently large,}
$$
which in turn is the same as (if we work out $I_b^\infty$ explicitly)
$$
\int\frac{e^{-b(1+|y|^2)+ixy}}{1+|y|^2}\,dy \to 0.\quad (**)
$$
So I think it remains to show
$
\int\frac{e^{-b(1+|y|^2)}}{1+|y|^2}\,dy\to 0
$.
So I rewrite the integral as
$$
\int \frac{e^{-b(1+|y|^2)}}{1+|y|^2} \,dy=\int_0^\infty
 \int_{|y|=R} \frac{e^{-b(1+R^2)}}{1+|R|^2} dydR=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-b(1+R^2)}\omega_n R^{n-1}}{1+R^2} dR.
$$
Then we can use Gamma function to prove that it is so.

However, I deem my arguments as involved and not general. At (**), I can't imagine how harder it would be if $I_b^\infty$ could not be calculated out directly. Yet Evans takes (*)  for granted, not even bothering the interchange problem at all. I think there must be some easier and more general way to justify that but, what is it?

Comment: Evans just uses [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem). All you need is to justify the absolutely convergence of the double-integral. This theorem should appeared on your real analysis course. And I think that real analysis is a preliminary for reading Evans' PDE book.

Comment: @Feng Sorry I didn't learn my real analysis very well, though I had taken two courses about it. And I think it is also difficult to establish the absloute convergence of the integral for, if we take absoulte values, first integrate in $t$ and then in $y$, we will see that the factor $e^{ix\cdot y}$ vanishes (which has norm 1), and the integral is the same as integrate $1/(1+|y|^2)$ over the whole space, which I think is not convergent.

Comment: Oh, I think I have come up with a better way. We write the integral in $t$ into two parts, one on [b,∞), b>0, and this time the double integral absolutely converges. And it remains to deal with the integral on [0,b].

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Forgive me if I am making a trivial oversight, but I think Fubini’s theorem doesn’t apply unless $n=1$ (and the Fourier transform doesn’t exist at $x=0$ if $n\gt1$, and it may also fail to exist for other $x$). I think you need to instead consider powers $(1+|y|^k)^{-1}$ where $k\ge n+1$, to guarantee existence of the transform and interchangeability of the integrals with Fubini. It may be the case that the integrals are interchangeable anyway, but one must use a different device than Fubini.

The Fourier Transform has the lucky property that $|e^{ixy}|\equiv1$, which simplifies convergence computations. To use Fubini’s theorem, in the forms given in the [Wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), the standard hypotheses are equivalent to the claim that $(y,t)\mapsto e^{ixy}e^{-t(1+|y|^2)}$ is absolutely integrable through $\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_{[0,\infty)}$, regardless of the value of $x$.

We can compute:

> $$\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_0^\infty|e^{ixy}e^{-t(1+|y|^2)}|\d t\d y&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_0^\infty e^{-t(1+|y|^2)}\d t\d y\\&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac{1}{1+|y|^2}\d y\end{align}$$

One way to identify the last integral diverges ($n\gt1$) is through the [coarea formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula). In the notation of the article, if $u:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ maps $y\mapsto\|y\|$ then $u$ is Lipschitz with gradient a unit vector, and we can set $g(y)=(1+|y|^2)^{-1}$. Then: $$\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\frac{1}{1+|y|^2}\d y&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}g(y)|\nabla u(y)|\d y\\&=\int_{\Bbb R}\int_{u^{-1}(t)}g(x)\d H_{n-1}(x)\d t\\&=\int_0^\infty\int_{S(t)}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\d H_{n-1}(x)\d t\\&=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+t^2}H_{n-1}(S(t))\d t\\&=\sigma_n\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{n-1}}{1+t^2}\d t\\&=\begin{cases}\pi&n=1\\\infty&n\gt1\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Where the $\sigma_n$ are some known constants for the surface area of an $n$-sphere.

This doesn’t exclude the integrals from being interchangeable. However, we can’t use vanilla Fubini to justify the interchange here.

However, the same proof shows that we can use Fubini’s theorem to interchange the integrals if you instead consider the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+|y|^{n+1}}$.

Comment: I cannot select the integrand arbitrarily for it is used for solving Laplace's equation $\Delta u+u=f$, and after a Fouriour transform we turn the problem into deriving the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{f}/(1+|\lambda|^2)$, hence Bessel potential is indispensable.